# Translating Oracle Range Following Functionto BigQuery

Tags: sql, oracle, google-bigquery

I am having trouble translating the following oracle RANGE function to BigQuery. Oracle appears to allow decimal places on the date time field, but BigQuery does not. Below is the part of the query that needs to be translated:

```
case when substr(PHONE, 0, 3) not in ('123','345')
and total_count is null 
and identity is not null
and MAX(1) OVER(
PARTITION BY PHONE
ORDER BY 
      START_DATE_AND_TIME
RANGE between 0.000023148148 FOLLOWING AND 0.003472222 FOLLOWING
) = 1 THEN
1
END as CALL
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In BigQuery, you need to translate the date/time value to a number.  For instance, for a certain number of seconds:

```
(CASE WHEN MAX(1) OVER (PARTITION BY PHONE 
                        ORDER BY UNIX_SECONDS(START_DATE_AND_TIME)
                        RANGE BETWEEN 2 FOLLOWING AND 300 FOLLOWING
                       ) = 1 THEN 1
 END)
```

Note:  In BigQuery, you would typically just create a boolean flag, rather than use `case`.